# Yii2 flash messages rendered automatically

Tags: yii2, flash-message

Controller:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['emailto']) && $model->save()) {
    \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thanks.');
} 
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

I have a form in view file, and when I click submit button, page reloads and flash message is displayed, but I don't have any hasFlash or getFlash in view file.

When I add in view file:

```
<?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?>
```

there are displayed 2 messages. How to delete that one which displays automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is third parameter in `getFlash()` - set this to `true` to automatically delete message that has been displayed.

```
<?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success', null, true) ?>
```